# Is there a special context for the deep parameter in the importNode function?

Tags: javascript, html

I came across the `importNode` function for the first time yesterday and I don't understand the deep parameter. The Mozilla documentation says:

> A boolean flag, whose default value is false, which controls whether
> to include the entire DOM subtree of the externalNode in the import.
> If deep is set to true, then externalNode and all of its descendants
> are copied. If deep is set to false, then only externalNode is
> imported - the new node has no children.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode?retiredLocale=de

If I try and set the deep parameter to true it works and the whole parent element is copied. But if I set the deep parameter to false nothing happens. Here is the moment that I realize that I haven't really understood the documentation here. Why do I need the deep = false?

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector(".deep-true");
const btn2 = document.querySelector(".deep-false");
btn1.addEventListener("click", appendElement_1.bind())
btn2.addEventListener("click", appendElement_2.bind())

function appendElement_1() {
  const parent = document.querySelector("div .parent");
  const node = document.importNode(parent, true);
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}

function appendElement_2() {
  const parent = document.querySelector("div .parent");
  const node = document.importNode(parent, false);
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}
.parent {
  background: green;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <p>hello <span>World</span></p>
      <h1>Bye</h1>      
    </div>

  </div>

  <button class="deep-true">ImportNode (deep: true)</button>
  <button class="deep-false">ImportNode (deep: false)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You say `"nothing happens"` - have you looked at the DOM tree with the console tools? The empty `div.parent` will be appended to the document body when `false` is used as the argument to `cloneNode` but the entire `div.parent` with all contents is appended when true is used.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius You are right! It copies only the ydiv parent container without child elements. Now i understand what the documentation try to explain. Thank you very much and have i nice weekend :-)

Comment: I updated my question and now it shows what happens. Merci @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to illustrate the `deep` argument and how the selected node is used a slightly modified version of the original code that simply adds the outerHTML to a textarea so that it is apparent what is happening.

```js
const d=document;

const evthandler=(e)=>{
  d.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML=d.importNode( d.querySelector("div#app .parent"), parseInt( e.target.dataset.deep ) ).outerHTML
}

d.querySelector(".deep-true").addEventListener("click", evthandler )
d.querySelector(".deep-false").addEventListener("click", evthandler )
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="parent">PARENT
    <div class="child">CHILD
      <p>hello <span>World</span></p>
      <h1>Bye</h1>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <button data-deep=1 class="deep-true">ImportNode (deep: true)</button>
  <button data-deep=0 class="deep-false">ImportNode (deep: false)</button>
</div>

<textarea cols=50 rows=6></textarea>
```

Comment: :-) Thank you! I add some styles to parent (updated my question) and it show also very well that somethink is happend!

Comment: Good luck with further coding adventures ;-)

Comment: Every day brings a new adventure.  Btw cool Name!